# Can I get LVM to check if my mirrors are consistent?

Tags: lvm

I'm using LVM mirroring. Following some disk issues I'm concerned about the consistency of the data in my mirrors. Is there anyway I can get LVM to physically compare the data in each mirror?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process is called raid scrubbing, as far as I can see it is supported in Redhat 6.5, not sure about the distro you use.

Comment: any link about lvm raid scrubbing?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=985976

Comment: Thanks! I proposed an edit to the answer to include the command that needs to be run too. Unfortunately it's not available in my distro, but I'll see if I can upgrade soon.

Comment: The edit was rejected - perhaps it is a bit too significant a change to someone else's answer - so I've posted another answer with the details.

Answer (score 8):

It seems from [the ticket that added scrubbing](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=985976) that the relevant command is:

```
lvchange --syncaction check vg/lv
```

Then wait for `lvs -o sync_percent` to reach 100% and check that `lvs -o mismatches` is 0.

I'm unable to test this for myself at present due to not having a recent enough version of LVM.

Thanks to lacasitos and c4f4t0r for the pointers.

Full command to checkout progress/state for Fedora 30:

```
sudo lvs -o +raid_sync_action,raid_mismatch_count
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: `lvs -o raid_mismatch_count`